# i am not able to show data from firebase in my react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to show categories of items in div with class name items but this div is not rendering on screen i can only see section tag on inspect please explain what i am doing wrong

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import firebase from "../../Firebase.config";
import './CategoriesPage.css'

const CategoriesPage = () => {
  const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("Categories")
  const [data, setdata] = useState([])
  const [loader, setloader] = useState(true)

  function getData() {
    const items = []
    ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        items.push(doc.data())
      })
    })
    setdata(items)
    setloader(false)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <section className="Categoriebox">{
      loader === true && [data].map((dev) => {
        <div className="items" key={dev.id}>
          <h1>{dev.name}</h1>
        </div>
      })
    }

    </section>
  )
};

export default CategoriesPage;
```

Comment: do you see any error in console/network tabs?

Comment: also I don't why you're using `loader` as a condition to show `data` and you're changing it to `false` after `setData(items)` ?

Comment: react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Comment: .map is not working , I am able to see data with console.log(data) but map is not rendering it in html

Comment: you either should remove this condition `loader === true` or change it to `!loader && data.map`, you're checking if `loader` is `true` while setting it to `false` after `setdata(items)`